# How to only hide download options from pdf files using p:media?

Tags: primefaces

How to only hide download options from pdf files using p:media?

```
<p:media id="schemeMediaOutput" cache="false" 
         value="#{pdfViewerBean.streamedContent}"
         style="min-width:820px; min-height:500px"
         width="auto" height="auto" player="pdf">
  <f:param name="#toolbar" value="0"></f:param>
</p:media>
```

Comment: I wanted to hide or disable the download button from PDF file toolbar and i am using primeface media streamed content. <p:media id="schemeMediaOutput" cache="false" value="#{pdfViewerBean.streamedContent}" style="min-width:820px; min-height:500px" width="auto" height="auto" player="pdf">
<f:param name="#toolbar" value="0"> </f:param>
</p:media>

Comment: I have used  <f:param name="#toolbar" value="0"> , But entire toolbar got vanished .I want only download button to be disabled.

Comment: AFAIK you can't. Also, any solution like this would be browser-specific - which is not good. If your reasoning is to protect from downloads you need to use a server-side solution that converts the document into something like a series of images.